# Numerous insert with a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in which I do processing (SELECT on the database).

According to the results of the requests, I do the insertion on a line in a database with some corresponding data.
I do this process thousands of time (with a while).

```
 SET @i = 0
 WHILE (@i <= (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM @Metadata ))
    BEGIN
        .....

        INSERT INTO [MyTable] (Field1, Field2,Field3...) VALUES (VALUE1, VALUE3, VALUE3 ...)
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
```

If I look to the performances, is it better to do like this or to store my results in a temporary table (in the while loop) and then to do only one insert from this temporary table ?

Is there something better ?

---

I add some information, may be I wasn't really clear:
- in input of my stored procedure I have a table valued (which has between 1000 and 5000 elements).
- for each line of this table (while loop), I do several SELECT on my database (according the results of the SELECT, I assign certain values to variables), et this is these values that I insert in my database (something like 1 insertion for each line of my table valued after processing).

Comment: just out of curiosity, where is the data coming from?

Comment: If you're going to stick with your while loop (as opposed to sets), as a quick optimisation, you could build up a command that inserts batches of rows. So your command would be initialised with the `INSERT INTO ...` and you would append a set of VALUES on each iteration of the loop. Then execute the command. Repeat in chunks until done.

Comment: Thank for your answers. I have added some information to be more clear. I am not stick with a while loop, but I don't know how to do it differently.

Comment: some data rows in insert table and for parameter will clarify your question to more extent

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tally table` plus `cross join` to do this.

```
WITH lv0 AS (SELECT 0 g UNION ALL SELECT 0)
    ,lv1 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv0 a CROSS JOIN lv0 b) -- 4
    ,lv2 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv1 a CROSS JOIN lv1 b) -- 16
    ,lv3 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv2 a CROSS JOIN lv2 b) -- 256
    ,lv4 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv3 a CROSS JOIN lv3 b) -- 65,536
    ,lv5 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv4 a CROSS JOIN lv4 b) -- 4,294,967,296
    ,Tally (n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM lv5)
SELECT VALUE1,
       VALUE3,
       VALUE3,...
FROM   your_source_table
       CROSS JOIN Tally
WHERE  n < = (SELECT Max(Id)
              FROM   @Metadata)
```

Comment: Thank for your answers. I have added some information to be sure I am clear. I don't know if I can use a tally table because I have several processing before the insertion, but may be I didn't understand correctly your answer.